# Moving from Zim to Org-Mode?

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode, transform

I would like to move all my file from Zim to Org Mode. I tried exporting as markdown stuff but Zim does not seem to be able to export all my stuff properly. I have a lot of files so I would like an automated way of moving from Zim to Org Mode if possible.

What are the possible ways to achieve smooth transition from Z to O?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't seem able to export properly?

Comment: It only exports couple pages and their sub folders when I ask Zim to export the whole Notebook

Answer (score 0):

there is a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script called [zim-to-org](https://github.com/vlad-lesin/zim-to-org) hosted on a github repostiroy just made for that purpose

from my personal experience, i can say that it converts elements (such as headings and list items) [zim](/questions/tagged/zim) to [org](/questions/tagged/org) format well except for check marks (todo list items) and that it also treats links to be wiki links (hence the `[[link|title]]` format) rather than pure org links, i guess it is for use with [org-wiki](https://caiorss.github.io/org-wiki/) emacs package/library

here is the information for usage:

```
zim-to-org is a simple zim directory notes to emacs orgmode file converter.

Usage: zim-to-org.pl <PATH>
where <PATH> is the path to zim notes.
Orgmode file will be printed to stdout.

The converter supports only zim tree to orgmode tree conversion,
it does support converting wiki-format to orgmode format, except headers,
which are converted to org-mode headers of corresponding level,
and zim page creation date.
```

it can convert the entire directory tree (ie. zim notebook) outputting the converted text in org format to the [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout) (ie. on terminal screen)

Comment: Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.